# Three-state inverting octal buffer

Tags: integrated-circuit, buffer, ttl

I'm looking for a three-state inverting octal buffer for a replacement part for an old microprocessor lab. The package should be DIP. Ucc should be on pin 20. Chip select should be at pins 1 and 19 and active on low, so that the buffer is in high impedance state unless both enables are low. The input/output ports should be next to each other with even pins as input and odd as output. What this would be in practice is a 74540 IC with the described pin configuration or a 74366 with 20 pins. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What part are you replacing?

Comment: Why are you giving us pin locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a [surface-mount version](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/74/74AC540.pdf) of the part, and combine it with a [SOIC-to-DIP card](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/495) to interface it with the old PCB.

Comment: my bad. fixed the links

Comment: @Teal will need a custom PCB to get the pinout he describes.

Comment: Or, he can use wires instead of pins when installing the PCB into his kit, making the connections as he needs them.

Comment: This seems like a roundabout way connecting a DIP or, rather, a DIP socket to the kit with wires, which is what I eventually did. The result looks about as awful as expected, but it'll work until someone decides to use lethal force against the chip for the second time. A PCB would probably made the soldering job cleaner and easier and the result simply better as a whole, but that would've been way too easy.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. Can't even buy an old buffer in DIP any longer. :( I didn't check, but maybe some type of programmable logic chip will do it (e.g. http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=428-1278-ND)

update: possibly [eaby](http://cgi.ebay.com/74HC244B-M74HC244B1-20PIN-DIP-X2-OCTAL-BUS-BUFFER-/370179348158?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item56306896be#ht_500wt_922)